# Insert a String Constant into a table using Select inside Inert Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, procedure

I want to insert a String constant into a table along with result of a select statement.

```
Create table SignatureCount(tableName VARCHAR(100), signatures VARCHAR(20));
...
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO SignatureCount (tableName, signatures) Select count(distinct signature),', tableName ,' from ', tableName); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Here **tableName** is a variable.

Problem is the SQL thinks that its a column name from the table an complains. However I could insert integer values like 1,2... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate SQL you want is something like

```
INSERT INTO SignatureCount(tableName, signatures)
    Select 'tablename', count(distinct signature),'
    from tableName;
```

I think this will generate it:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO SignatureCount(tableName, signatures) ',
                'Select ''', tablename, ''', count(distinct signature) ',
                'from ', tableName);
```

You need to be very careful with commas and single quotes in such an expression.

Actually, I often solve this using replace:

```
SET @s = REPLACE('INSERT INTO SignatureCount(tableName, signatures)
SELECT ''@tablename'', count(distinct signature) from @tablename',
                 '@tablename', tableName);
```

That makes it easier to see (and fix) the structure of the query.